# Взять значение переменной по адресу

Tags: c, указатели

У меня есть переменная типа `long long`. Если ее значение больше 10000 - это адрес, по которому лежит настоящее значение переменной. Как найти значение переменной?

Comment: Хотите рассмотреть `int` как указатель? `int a = ????; if (a > 10000) {int *pa = static_cast<int*>(a); printf("%d", *pa);}`. Но в тех редких случаях, когда надо рассматривать число как указатель, лучше использовать беззнаковые числа.

Comment: @maestro Да, мне надо рассмотреть `int` как указатель. но приведение (я пытаюсь сделать `(int*)a`, ведь у меня чистый C) не работает

Comment: Если `a` содержит валидный указатель, то работает. Если нет - SIGSEGV. Проверьте также разрядность: если у вас 64 бит, то надо использовать `long int`. https://onlinegdb.com/BqOkxD6dT

Comment: Должно работать `*(int*)a`. Если вы все рассказали точно и полно...

Comment: На большинстве современных машин (которые 64 битные) размера `int` будет недостаточно для хранения адреса. Так что это не будет работать.

Comment: в условии `long long`, поправил

Comment: @BigCubeCat это полный таск? Где вообще найти этому реальное применение

Comment: @TheRyuTeam Это учебная задача